# How can I cause UIScrollView to lock 2 out of 3 UIViews when scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6.3, iOS 6.2, ARC and Storyboards) which has the following structure on the bottom half of one of the scenes  (all of the grids are UIViews, as is SubViewData).

[image]

The purpose is to have something that looks like a spreadsheet; I need to be able to scroll horizontally and the Left Grid will stay locked and if I scroll vertically, the Top Grid will stay locked.

This what it looks like now, without the scrolling (there is more to the right and also down):

[image]

**UPDATE:**  This is the code that defines the UIViews:

[image: Had to use an image because I couldn't get it formatted correctly]

I have looked in SO and Google and found no examples of this.  Can someone please tell me what I need to change to get this code to work properly, or give me some good docs where I can get detailed information on **contentOffset**?  (I have already read the UIScrollView, and it's no help!)

**SOLVED** - it's now working... this is how I got it to work, with the help of Fogmeister:

- created a separate top row and left row UIView to hold the grid hours and staff names
- embedded those new UIViews in UIScrollViews (Editor -> Embedd in scroll view)
- followed the instructions from Fogmeister with regard to the code to make it happen.

This is the new structure:

[image]

And this is the code to make it happen:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView  {

CGPoint mainOffset = [scrollView contentOffset];
NSLog(@"\n\nmainOffset.x: %f\nmainOffset.y: %f", mainOffset.x, mainOffset.y);

// set the horizontal offset of the main view onto the column headers
[self.topGridSV setContentOffset:CGPointMake(mainOffset.x, 0)];
if(mainOffset.x < 0)  {
    [self.topGridSV setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self.schedScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}

// set the vertical offset onto the row headers
[self.leftGridSV setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, mainOffset.y)];
if(mainOffset.y < 0)  {
    [self.leftGridSV setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self.schedScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}
```

Comment: By any chance are you using Auto Layout in the storyboard?

Comment: Can you show the code for LeftGrid.h please. (Just the beginning few lines if possible).

Comment: Not using AutoLayout... here's the code (I think this is what you are looking for)...
  
@interface LeftGrid : UIView  {
    
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the way I'd do this is to move the "header" row and column into their own scroll view.

So you'll have a scrollview in the middle with the actual cells in.

Then you'll have a scroll view along the top that ONLY CONTAINS the column headers.

Then have a scroll view down the left that ONLY CONTAINS the row headers.

Now, make the "owning" view controller the delegate of the "main" scrollView with the cells in.

So you'll have...

```
UIScrollView *cellScrollView;
UIScrollView *columnHeaderScrollView; // along the top
UIScrollView *rowHeaderScrollView; // down the left
```

You will have to set the content accordingly. Obviously, you don't want the headers in the cellScrollView. etc...

Now, in the delegate method...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // scrollView here should always be == self.cellScrollView
    // as this is where the delegate method is triggered from.

    CGPoint *mainOffset = [scrollView contentOffset];

    // set the horizontal offset of the main view onto the column headers
    [self.columnHeaderScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(mainOffset.x, 0)];

    // set the vertical offset onto the row headers
    [self.rowHeaderScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, mainOffset.y)];
}
```

Something like this should easily get the effect you're after.

**With one scroll view**

You will have three sub views of the scroll view and references to these...

```
cellView
leftView
topView
```

These are all subclasses of UIView.

Initially you will have a layout of something like...

```
leftView frame == [0, 50, 80, some long height]
topView frame == [80, 0, some long width, 50]
cellView frame == [80, 50, some long width, some long height]
```

i.e. the cell view will be indented by the height of the top view and the width of the left view. (I hope this makes sense).

So in your scrollViewDidScroll...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // we will transform the position of the top view and left view using the offset.
    // I chose a transform as it always acts from the original position.
    // changing the view's frame will make it difficult to set it back again.

    CGPoint offset = [scrollView contentOffset];

    // move the left view to the left and right depending on the offset
    leftView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(offset.x, 0);
    // up and down is taken care of by the scroll view correctly.

    // move the top view up and down depending on the offset
    topView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, offset.y);
    // left and right is taken care of by the scroll view correctly.
}
```

I chose to use transform as it make the calculations easier. Instead of trying to calculate the difference in position required each time, you just set the transform amount to the offset and it works.

Comment: Hmmm... is there no way to do this with only one (1) scrollview?  I know it can be done, but not sure how...

Comment: Yeah, it's def possible. Let me edit to show how it could be done.

Comment: Build errors: Property 'transform' cannot be found in forward class object 'LeftGrid'  I did NOT use the frame code of yours, since the grids were built using Storyboard... was it necessary?  

  I used my object's names... they are all UIViews... apparently 'transform' is not valid?

Comment: You will need to add either the QuartzCore or CoreGraphics framework. I can't remember which. (I think CoreGraphics).

Comment: transform is definitely valid for UIView... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4

Comment: RE your question. This code will work whether created in code or in storyboards. Once you have CoreGraphics in your project the transform code will build and work.

Comment: I added both frameworks; still getting the build errors... let me update the question to show the definitions...

Comment: Not using AutoLayout... here's the code (I think this is what you are looking for)... @interface LeftGrid : UIView { } –

Comment: OK... so since none of this works, let's talk about the first method you described, using a UIScrollView for each (top, left and middle).    Can I achieve this by doing Editor->Embed in Scroll View for the left and top?  Then give the scrollViews identities, and I should be good to go, yes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32791/discussion-between-fogmeister-and-spokane-dude)